# Как стилизовать input[type=""]?

Tags: html, css, css3, input, label

Подскажите,  как можно стилизовать `input[type="radio"]` и `input[type="checkbox"]` (без разницы) таким образом, чтобы активный пункт при его выборе полностью обводился в рамку, т.е. вот так

```css
.primer { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="primer">
<label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="" value="1" checked="checked">Пример</label>
</div>
```

Разметка такая, и меняться не должна:

```html
<label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="" value="1" checked="checked">Один</label>
<label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="" value="1">Два</label>
<label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="" value="1">Три</label>
```

т.е. `input` обернут в `label`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для данной разметки проще использовать js или jquery:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") === true) {
    $(this).closest('label').addClass('check').siblings().removeClass('check');
  } else if ($(this).prop("checked") === false) {
    $(this).closest('label').removeClass('check');
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

label.check {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="val" value="1" checked="checked">Один</label>
<label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="val" value="1">Два</label>
<label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="val" value="1">Три</label>
```

Если все же есть возможность вставить внутрь `label` еще тег, например, `span`, то:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

label>input:checked~span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="val" value="1" checked="checked">Один <span></span></label>
  <label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="val" value="1">Два <span></span></label>
  <label class="product--items"><input type="radio" class="radio" name="val" value="1">Три <span></span></label>
```

Comment: @LADYX,  Спасибо! ❄❄❄❄❄❄❄❄❄

Comment: @Sevastopol', спасибо! Взаимно! ;)

Comment: На гридах можно сделать используя только css. Хм.. А пожалуй, без гридов тоже можно тем же способом, даже проще...

Answer (score 1):

В хроме работает, в FF какая-то дичь...

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label::before {
  content: "";
  order: 2;
  flex: 0 0 0px;
  min-width: calc(100% + 1em);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: -1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

input {
  order: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin-left: 0;
}

:checked {
  margin-left: calc(-100% + 2px - 1.5em);
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Один</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Два</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Три</label>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol', ну вообще тут в коде дичь, но хром как-то понял))

Comment: @Sevastopol', margin в процентах в контейнере, на ширину которого влияет этот margin - это дичь)

Answer (score 1):

Придумал более-менее нормальное решение:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template: 100% 100% 100% / auto auto;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  gap: 0 .25em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label::before {
  content: "";
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

label::after {
  content: "";
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -200%;
  margin: 0 -.5em;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
}

input:checked {
  grid-row: 2;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Один</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Два</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Три</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

И теоретически самый нормальный способ.. А практически, что-то чекбокс в хроме размытый получился - похоже, ему горизонтальные линии между пикселями порезали...

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  top: -200%;
  margin: 0 -.5em;
}

input {
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input:checked {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Один</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Два</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Три</label>
```